# Как подключитьContact Form 7 не шорткодом

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Скажите пожалуйста, Contac Form 7 можно вставлять в файл НЕ шорткодом, а при помощи указания id  или класса в контейнере, а внутри уже input. И чтобы имел возможности добавлять кастомные input, свои дополнительные данные. Нужно будет данные вукомерса сохранять. Можно ли обозначить в файле контейнер и вставлять просто input(ы)?
Или может есть другой плагин...

Понимаете, я бы с удовольствием использовал Contact Form 7, но у меня поля разбиты по двум табам. То есть и во втором и в третьем табе есть поля. А кнопка отправить вообще должна находиться вне табов, ниже! То есть я не могу в один таб добавить шорткод

Comment: [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) Переформулируй вопрос

Comment: Разметку табов надо вставить в форму CF7 - это самый простой путь.

Comment: Вы сами поняли что спросили? Дело в том, что Contact Form 7 - это не просто кусочек HTML, это и скрипты и PHP часть. Как у Вас будет работать Contact Form 7, и что будет обрабатывать результат, если Вы отсечёте всю логику и код??? Однако, в  Contact Form 7 есть хуки и способы вызова через PHP, есть к нему и  плагины, да и вообще есть другие плагины форм, где и пошаговые формы и несколько колоночные есть. Что Вас заставляет отрубать Contact Form 7 руки и ноги, ради того, что бы на голову одеть очки?

Comment: Sergio, я не знаю о чём вы и что и где я отрубал. Вы не верно поняли информацию. 

"Однако, в Contact Form 7 есть хуки и способы вызова через PHP"  -  а как можно вызвать CF7 через php? И можно ли вызывать и вставлять inputы CF7? Вот  об этом я и пишу.

Comment: В php вызывается через do_shortcode()